# page break on number of rows in drill down ssrs report

Tags: visual-studio-2012, reporting-services, page-break

i have a drill down report in SSRS (vs2012) that consists of group only.  i need to have page breaks based on a parameter of number of rows per page user specifies.  i added a group that is a parent to all other drill down groups and checked the page break between each instance of a group.

the group is using this expression:

=Ceiling(RowNumber("table1")/Parameters!recordsPerPage.Value)

the problem is it counts the rows in the dataset.

how do i group and page break based only on the number of visible rows?

thanks, Inna

Answer (score 0):

I would remove that parameter - you have gone too far in trying to control SSRS.